# React Native - how to create a background service

Tags: android, react-native

I am looking forward to switch my app to rect-native from native. I have an app which track the user's GPS location even when the application is closed. How can I achieve this in react native.

I had a look into Headless JS and tried with the following and it doesn't work

in Manifest

```
<application>
...
<service android:name="com.BackgroundService" />
...
</application>
```

index.android.js

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('geolocation', () => geolocation);
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => require('./SomeTaskName'));
```

SomeTaskName.js

```
import SocketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
module.exports = async (taskData) => {
    // do stuff
    var socket = SocketIOClient('http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:4000');
    socket.emit("test");
}
```

BackgroundService.java

```
package com;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;
public class BackgroundService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {

  @Override
  protected @Nullable
  HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
          "SomeTaskName",
          Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
          5000);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.geolocation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import com.BackgroundService;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackgroundService.class);
        this.startService(service);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */

    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "geolocation";
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have solution for this?